# Remove Pagenumber from first page of index

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

I have a multiple page-long index in an extarticle document.
However, I am trying to remove the page number (of the bottom of the page) for the whole index.

using `\pagestyle{empty}`and/or `\thispagestyle{empty}` resulted in *all* (footnote-)page numbers getting removed (like expected) *but* the (footnote-)page number of the first page of the index.

Is there any fix to this?
I tried multiple approaches but had no luck until now.

### Addendum

*edit1*: Indeed, I can only set the page-numbering style of all index-pages BUT the first one. (using fancyhdr and `\pagestyle{fancy}`

*edit2*: As I am using a custom `.ist` for index generation: I tried adding `\pagestyle{empty}` to it. But this has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Heiko.
However, this was a way easier (and for me sufficient) fix:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble} % remove page numbering 
\printindex
\pagenumbering{arabic} % reset numbering style
```

Answer (score 4):

Many classes use `\thispagestyle{plain}` for the first page of a chapter. Since you are using a custom `.ist` file, there is an easy workaround. The key `preamble` can be set to add `\thispagestyle{plain}`, e.g.:

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}\\thispagestyle{empty}\n"
```

If class **`memoir`** is used, the page style for the first index page can be changed via:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\aliaspagestyle{indextitlepagestyle}{empty}
```

Or if all first pages of chapters including the index should be have an empty page style:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}
```

**KOMA-Script** provides the macro `\indexpagestyle`, which contains the page style for the first index page. It can be redefined as:

```
\renewcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{empty}
```

An empty page style for the first pages of the other chapters are set by:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}
```

In the standard classes as **`report`** or **`book`**, the page style is hard coded. If the page style `plain` should be replaced by `empty` in *all* cases, the page style can be redefined:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

If the page style should be changed in `theindex` only, then it can be patched:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\theindex{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{%
  \errmessage{Could not patch \string\theindex}%
```